# Apache won't start on XAMPP in windows xp

Tags: apache, xampp

I have installed **Xampp** and am trying to start the apache server but it doesen't work. When I click on the start button on **XAMPP control panel** then the following message is appear::

```
 4:24:48 AM  [Apache]   Attempting to start Apache app...
 4:24:49 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: running
 4:24:49 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: stopped
 4:24:49 AM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
 4:24:49 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
 4:24:49 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
 4:24:49 AM  [Apache]   Check the "/xampp/apache/logs/error.log" file
 4:24:49 AM  [Apache]   and the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
 4:25:15 AM  [main]     Executing "d:\xampp\apache"
```

if i try it with the batch file well it gives me this error:

```
 Diese Eingabeforderung nicht waehrend des Running beenden
 Bitte erst bei einem gewollten Shutdown schliessen
 Please close this command only for Shutdown
 Apache 2 is starting ...

 httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 452 of D:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax e
 rror on line 17 of D:/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf: Cannot load /xam
 pp/php/php5ts.dll into server: This application has failed to start because the
 application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix thi
 s problem.

 Apache konnte nicht gestartet werden
 Apache could not be started
 Press any key to continue . .
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: Post "line 452 of D:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf" here, let's see what is it whining about

Comment: Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"

Comment: Sorry, I haven't read error message till the end - the real problem is in PHP installation: "Cannot load /xampp/php/php5ts.dll into server: This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect"

Comment: Well, try uninstalling, erasing d:\xampp and then reinstalling

Comment: I already erasing xampp from E:\xampp and then install xampp in d:\xampp and show the above message again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have to download **Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)** so go to the following link and download it then install it. problem will be solved.[check this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

Answer (score 2):

uninstall it and reinstall. But during re-installation check start xampp and any other services you want this will start the service automatically for you it has happen to me but on win7 
this happens when the port 80 is been use by an other services os try stopping all services before reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

This might not relate to your occasion, but the most frequent cause of Apache failing on my PC is when I forget to kill Skype beforehand. It uses the same 80 port.

Comment: Then let us see line 452 of D:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"